# Google Maps not working with Meteor AT ALL - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, cordova, meteor

I've tried geolocation, standard maps, cloning repositories, and any other way I can think of to create a reactive Google map in Meteor and I have been unsuccessful. It displays fine in the browser, but not when I package it for iOS. I know the element it there; I put a border on the map and it shows up.

I packaged the same code in Cordova and it worked like a charm.

Why would it work in the browser and not on the device?

Here's one of the pieces of code: https://github.com/jondamato/gmap-meteor-issue

Answer (score 0):

Your app shouldn't be working at all in `production mode`. This is because you have two files `map.js` and `meteor.js`

In your `meteor.js` when you run `onRendered` you call `initialize();`. This method is variable scoped to the `map.js` file and not available outside of `map.js` due to file level variable scoping.

To expose the `initialize();` method you have to write it like this:

```
initialize = function() { ... }
```

Without the `var` keyword or without using `function initialize() {..`

It works on the browser because of the window dom event in `map.js`

Comment: I made the changes and it's still a no-go. If you got it working, could you share the code? thanks

Comment: Also, how can I test my app out of production mode? I know I can deploy to appname.meteor.com, but how would I tell my "native" app to point to that url?

Comment: @jondamato The change in my answer + removing the code that you have in the `<script>` tag in maps.html that runs initialize again makes it work for me. On the iphone you also need geolocation permissions which you need to set up in xcode. May be easier to add this package in `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.geolocation@0.3.12` to do the permissions for you. To test in production mode use the `--production` flag when you run `meteor` in whichever environment you require